Euclidean Rotation $e^{\pi \hat{K}_x}$ and a paradox in the Wightman function
You may be familiar with the fact that the antipodal map $-I$ is an element of $SO(d)$ when $d$ is even, and is continuously connected to the identity. For $SO(d-1,1)$ the antipodal map is continuously connected to the identity if one "analytically continues" group elements. In other words, if one defines the boost and rotation generators
$$
K_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \hspace{0.5 cm} L_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
M = e^{i \pi K_x} e^{\pi L_x}  = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is the antipodal map $-I$. Let us now promote the matrices $K_x$ and $L_x$ to the quantum operators $i \hat{K}_x$ and $i \hat{L}_x$. Then
$$
\hat{M} = e^{\pi \hat{K}_x} e^{-i \pi \hat{L}_x}, \hspace{1cm} \hat{M}^{-1} = e^{-\pi \hat{K}_x} e^{i \pi \hat{L}_x}
$$
satisfy, for a free massless scalar field,
$$
\hat{M}^{-1} \hat{\phi}(X) \hat{M} = \hat{\phi}(-X).
$$
However, this gives an apparent contradiction. The Wightman function is
$$
G_+(X,Y) = \langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(X) \hat{\phi}(Y) |0\rangle = \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \frac{1}{(X^0 - Y^0 - i \epsilon)^2 - (\vec{X} - \vec{Y})^2 }.
$$
However,
\begin{align}
\langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(X) \hat{\phi}(Y) |0\rangle &= \langle 0 | \hat{M}^{-1} \hat{\phi}(X) \hat{M} \hat{M}^{-1} \hat{\phi}(Y) \hat{M}|0\rangle \\
&= \langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(-X) \hat{\phi}(-Y)|0\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \frac{1}{(X^0 - Y^0 + i \epsilon)^2 - (\vec{X} - \vec{Y})^2 } \\
& \neq \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \frac{1}{(X^0 - Y^0 - i \epsilon)^2 - (\vec{X} - \vec{Y})^2 } = \langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(X) \hat{\phi}(Y) |0\rangle.
\end{align}
which is a contradiction. We were able to prove that the Wightman function is equal to complex conjugate of itself, which is not true due to the $i \epsilon$, which matters on the lightcone.
What is the resolution to this apparent paradox? Certainly it must have to do with the fact that $e^{\pi \hat{K}_x}$ is not a well-defined operator on all states in the Hilbert space, but what is the diagnostic criterion which shows "why" we aren't allowed to use this operator in this way, when it is common to use operators like this in related contexts, such as in deriving the KMS condition for thermal Greens functions?

First of all quantum fields admit a unitary representation of  the special orthochronous Poincaré group. Existence of representations of larger groups as the whole special Poincaré one as you consider is not automatic, both from the physical and mathematical perspective: it deserves further investigation. In general representations for enlarged Poincaré groups do not exist. In particular “extensions” of mathematical manipulations of selfadjoint generators of the restricted group generally fail.
Nevertheless the spacetime inversion can in fact be implemented for real scalar fields -- in particular as aconsequence of the CPT theorem -- (and this representation  plays also  a role il the Bisognano-Wickmann-Sewell theorem in relation to the Unruh effect and the KMS condition). But, at quantum level, it has to be interpreted as an antiunitary operator as it includes the time reversal.
So there is an antiunitary map $M: H\to H$ such that it preserves the vacuum:
$$M\Omega = \Omega\tag{1}$$
and acts as the inversion on (real scalar) quantum fields:
$$M^{-1} \Phi(X)M =\Phi(-X).\tag{2}$$
As a consequence of anti unitarity and selfadjointness of field operators:
$$\langle M\Omega|M\Phi(X)\Phi(Y)\Omega\rangle = \overline{\langle\Omega | \Phi(X)\Phi(Y)\Omega\rangle}=\langle \Omega|\Phi(Y)\Phi(X)\Omega\rangle.$$
According to (1) and (2), the left most hand side amounts to
$$\langle \Omega|\Phi(X)MM^{-1}\Phi(Y)M\Omega\rangle=\langle \Omega|\Phi(-X)\Phi(-Y)\Omega\rangle.$$
In summary,
$$\langle \Omega|\Phi(-X)\Phi(-Y)\Omega\rangle= \langle \Omega|\Phi(Y)\Phi(X)\Omega\rangle$$
that boils down to your result for the distributional  kernels of the two-point functions in case of a free massles scalar fields: swapping $X$ and $Y$ is the same as reversing the sign of $\epsilon$. I finally observe that $M$ implements the CPT symmetry (here C is trivial).
